# how do i have my back ground filter cut off with the picture

Tags: html, css

I added a liner gradient to make the background picture darker, but i want the part i shaded in red to simply be the default background color/white, heres the pic(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rdEi.jpg)

i tried to use the height attribute and give it a height of 500 px but this didnt do anything. Im very new to programming and just started a week ago sorry if this is a stupid question.

The reason i have the background size set to 1450px is because the picture zooms in alot if i dont set a size.

```
body {
  
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80)), url(imgs/satbackgroundp3.png) no-repeat; 
  background-size: 1450px;

}
```

heres the css for the background

Comment: It isn't possible to help here without guessing until we see the relevant HTML structure plus a description of how the part that is not to be shaded is defined (e.g. is it just the end of the content in some element?). Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a linear gradient of black over it, you should add a blend mode. Also, instead of setting the size (which won't work on all devices) use background-size: cover.
Try this:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rdEi.jpg");
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: thank you for telling me about blend mode, the issue is when i do cover, the picture zooms in the cover the whole page. if you look at the screenshot i want the picture to stop at the same place, but for the space under it to be white. and when i change backrgound size to 1450 again and no repeat, the space under is still dark gray. as shown in the previous screenshot.